# Give input to stdio in gdb with python

Tags: python, debugging, gdb, reverse-engineering

I want to debug app with gdb which gets two inputs from stdin, to understand my situation, This is example program which i want to debug.

1. Program prints something like "Hello world", then asks for input.
2. from python script, inputs 5 to stdin. ( This is static )
3. The program prints "123"
4. The python script inputs "123" ( inputs what program printed )
5. Program exits

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Thank you @Jortega for responding, my issue is solved. I'll post solution soon.